# TypeScript in Visual Studio - stop intellisense errors

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have a VS project with some TypeScript files in it. The build action for all the files is set to "None". However, the error list and Intellisense continues to look at the files and report errors.

I've tried making a tsconfig file with an exclude list, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Is there some way to get Visual Studio to stop looking at these files?

Comment: I'm interested if there is a 'correct' answer for this. I've had to do this in the past before, and the only way I could get around it, was to exclude the files from the project, which is far from ideal.

Comment: Visual Studio or VSCode?

Comment: @Eugenio Visual Studio. I would have used the VSCode tag if it were for VSCode.